# Sending a JSZip zip file to Java

Tags: java, spring, angular, jszip

My goal is to upload a zip file to my Angular 2 front-end, send it to my Java (Spring Boot) back-end and process the xml files contained in the zip.

I am using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to upload the zip files to my Angular 2 application (but feel free to propose other solutions).

The thing is I don't know how to send the zip file from the front-end, and how to receive it in the back-end.

At the moment I am sending the JSZip object which, looks like this :

```
{  
   "files":{  
      "file1.xml":{  
         "name":"file1.xml",
         "dir":false,
         "date":"2017-05-17T11:43:24.000Z",
         "comment":null,
         "unixPermissions":33188,
         "dosPermissions":null,
         "_data":{  
            "compressedSize":1408,
            "uncompressedSize":7120,
            "crc32":-1714370258,
            "compression":{  
               "magic":"\b\u0000"
            },
            "compressedContent":{  
               "0":165,
               "1":89,
               "2":93,
               "3":147,
               (...)
               "1348":54
            }
         },
         "_dataBinary":true,
         "options":{  
            "compression":null,
            "compressionOptions":null
         }
      },
      "file2.xml":{
        (...)
      }
   },
   "comment":null,
   "root":""
}
```

How do I handle this data in Java, and how do I process the xml files ?

Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/307),

I tried this :

```
@PostMapping(path = "zip")
public void importZip(@RequestBody final byte [] zipBytes) throws IOException {
        final ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes));
        zipStream.getNextEntry();
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    }
```

But `entry` is always `null` and nothing is displayed.

How can I do this please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know JSZip but it seems to me a front end utility able in creating, reading and editing ZIP files. It doesn't upload the file from the client to the server. So I guess you must use some Angular uploader function to upload the zip file to the server. Moreover I guess it will be transferred by using multipart so you should not use the @RequestBody annotation

Comment: I am sending the `JSZip` object with `http.post(url, jszipObject)`, my Java back-end does receive it but I don't know how to process it.

Comment: @Wenneguen Any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [generateAsync](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html) function of JSZip. That way you can transfer the actual binary zip file as a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (as opposed to the JSZip object structure).

```js
// In javascript using JSZip version 3.x.x:
const jszipObject = new JSZip();
// Add the actual files
jszipObject.file('file1.xml', '<actual>file contents</actual>')
// 'blob' will yield a javascript Blob. You could alternatively use 'bytestring'.
// You can find all the options at the link above to the documentation
jszipObject.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(binaryData => {
    const url = "http://some.url";
    http.post(url, binaryData)
});
```